# Excel Getting bad text to column results - need the 10s digit number out of these cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

So for these items I want,

```
2,2,6,2,6,8
```

cells

```
21.00
22.00
68.00
821.00
67.00
86.00
```

I found an example that did

```
=MID(A1, FIND(".", A1)+1, 1)
```

but that does not work

I also thought of modding the value - but can't seem to get that to work either
suggestions?

Comment: If you want to have `2,2,6,1,6,8` out of the given list and you say you want the 10s, where does the `1` in the list come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the formula:

```
=RIGHT(INT(A1/10),1)
```

I should note that my formula returns the number as a string, whereas t_m's answer returns the number as a number.  My string response will be converted to a numeric value by many, but not all, Excel functions, so which will work better will depend on what you want to do with the result.

Of course, mine could be converted to a number by various techniques:

```
=--RIGHT(INT(A1/10),1)
=VALUE(RIGHT(INT(A1/10),1))
```

etc

Answer (score 1):

Formula from Excel 2013 using MOD function

```
=(MOD(F3|100)-MOD(F3|10))/10
```